# Press a focused button in Maxscript

Tags: maxscript

I was wanting to press a focused button in Maxscript using standard buttons if possible. I think this would be easily done using a .NET button but I was just curious if it was possible to press the focused button using the standard MaxScript button control.

Here's the code I have which focuses the button but the the button event handler does work even though the button is focused. I assume it's because its a mouse click only event.

```
try destroyDialog testRol catch()
rollout testRol "testRol" (

  button btn_yes "Y̲es" width:120 across:2
  button btn_no "N̲o" width:120

  on btn_yes pressed do destroyDialog testRol
  on btn_no pressed do print "Oh no.."

  on testRol open do setFocus btn_yes

  )
createDialog testRol 525 45
OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to press mxs button, use its handle:

```
on testRol open do UIAccessor.PressButton btn_yes.hWnd[1]
```

If you want to press the focused button, get its handle and use it the same way:

```
on testRol open do
(
    local user32 = (python.import "ctypes").windll.user32
    setFocus btn_yes
    UIAccessor.PressButton (user32.GetFocus())
)
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question. I meant that when I opened this dialog and the button was focused, then pressing the enter key didn't press the button as you'd expect. I'll mark this as answered seeing as you have done that. Thanks.